# way to insert a new record, with cashier subscription?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am searching the web today to see if I can somehow be able to add a new record to some tables whenever the user memberships renew.

let's say we have an app have (users, notifications, subscriptions ) tabes.

when he subscribe the first time, I can add a new record in notification table within the same controller, but what if I want every time he renews his subscription a new instance can be added in the notification table?

Answer (score 0):

[Eloquent Model Event](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#events)

is the way to go, I believe.

Or if the logic is really simple, you can define it in your model class.

```php
     /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @param Builder
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::updated(function (Subscription $subscription) {
            // your subscription logic here...
        });
    }
```